# Why is the address of __libc_start_main always the same inside GDB even though ASLR is on?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, libc, aslr

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff7de8060 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) r
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/firstlove/projects/org-ioslide/example/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff7de8060 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) r
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/firstlove/projects/org-ioslide/example/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff7de8060 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) Quit
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

        Inferior 1 [process 16372] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
firstlove-pc% cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
2
```

IIUC, ASLR should randomize all address, including the one of `libc.so`, but I found that the address of `__libc_start_main()` is always `0x00007ffff7de8060` on my Linux machine, why? What is wrong?

Comment: Does address space randomization also randomize function addresses or only those of variables?

Comment: Do you see the same result if you start a new gdb session in which to check the address, instead of rerunning the program in the same gdb session?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have tried definitely

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you run a program inside `gdb`, `gdb` tries to help you debugging by disabling address randomization. You can use the following command to enable it (effective from the next run of the program):

```
set disable-randomization off
```